# Selecting two rows from a single table row in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `A (Id1, Id2, someValue)`

What I want to achieve in mySQL:

My `SELECT` query should return
two rows:

```
Id1, someValue
Id2, someValue
```

(based on a certain condition - for example, where someValue > N)

How can I achieve this without using `UNION`?

Comment: Why not use a `UNION`? I can't see any other way...

Comment: Why not use a `UNION` statement?

Comment: I don't want to use a Union because I don't want to duplicate the whole complex query which otherwise would be the same. The query which was given to me has seven tables left joined (okay, I know that's already not so efficient, but still). This particular condition is to be put with one of the joins.

Comment: Why would you need to retrieve data that way? If that's the default operation, you'd better change your db schema.

Comment: Do you want one row to be split into two or just that that for some rows you want to return column1 and column2 for others?

Comment: @RodrigoFerreira yes, perhaps I should do that. @ Salman A the latter.

Comment: @seminoobish: I've un-deleted my answer. You may want to revise the question title where it says *two rows from a single table row*.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is not possible without using `UNION`, here is how to archive this with it:

```
(SELECT ID1 as ID, someValue FROM A WHERE someValue > N)
UNION
(SELECT ID2 as ID, someValue FROM A WHERE someValue > N)
```

Comment: Use `UNION ALL`, otherwise MySQL will suppress duplicate rows and you might end up getting one row even if both queries returned one row each.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN somecondition THEN ID1
        ELSE ID2
    END AS ID, someValue
FROM that_table
```

The `somecondition` can be an expression similar to those that you use in a `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just use an or? for example:

```
select * from A where someValue = 'x' OR someValue 'y'
```

Comment: The result would be (Id1, Id2, someValue) while I need two rows (Id1, someValue) and (Id2, someValue). [I need two rows]

Comment: very true, sorry didnt look at your question properly, best off using a union!

Answer (score 0):

If you need the return in separated rows you'd better split the db schema to "id, someValue". On insert, just insert {id1_value, someValue}, {id2_value, someValue}, and on retrieve just select from table where value = someValue. You'll get the return you expect.

If you need to relate id1 and id2 in some way (make a linked list or whatever), you may add the related id to the entry. The schema could be
{id, value, related_id}.